# codeigniter, using global variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a codeigniter application with 5 controllers one is the 'base' and the rest are inheriting form it, i am using global variable in the base to load in the view but it's not working i get (Undefined variable) when i load the view how can I fix this?

i'm using this function in the base to load the views

```
function _setContent($tplFile) {
            ob_start();
            $this->load->view($this->theme_dir . '/' . $tplFile, $this->tplData);
            $_content = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();

            $this->tplData['_content'] = $_content;
            $this->load->view($this->theme_dir . '/default', $this->tplData);
        }

$this->tplData // is the global variable
```

Comment: Not answering your question but you can set `true` as the third parameter to the `view()` function to return the content rather than echo-ing it (so you dont need to use ob_* functions)

Comment: Mamoum, what's the exact message you get? It's strange you get the Undefined error for $this->tplData, are you sure the error doesn't come from the view, where you call array indexes you didn't pass have?

Comment: the error is it thhe views when I call the array indexes it says : Undefined variable ...

Answer (score 1):

you can use config class.

```
$this->config->set_item('global_variable', $my_var);
```

now you can use this variable wherever you want

```
$this->config->item('global_variable');
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `define()` instead of global to set your variable - http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Comment: logically speaking, define is for constants and in OP's logic that ISN'T a constant. Although both available gloablly, globals and constats have different purposes, they're not interchangable

Comment: Well, what is the type of "tplData" ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't find it clear, but since it's related to views I imagine it's something that changes from every method, so that one view loads something, another loads some other set of data and so on. If you define it as a constat, you need to redefine it everytime you want to pass the view different datas.

Comment: I agree with @DamienPirsy. Define doesn't seem like the right approach for this.

Comment: Looking at the code, $this->tplData should hold all the variables passed to the view. The more I think about it, the more making it a constant gets wrong. And the more I don't see the need of making it a global variable too.

Comment: @JulienMeilleur $this->tplData should be an array, by the way

Comment: @DamienPirsy You're right, it's an array containing variours template datas, and a global/constant doesn't seems to be the appropriate way to do it.
Mamoum you may try to create a setup function in your base file for "tplData"; or if we got it all wrong around here, please enlighen us (more details about the use of "tplData")

Comment: $this->tplData is array and it holds all the variable form all different function to the view

Comment: in one of my function i use it like this

 function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Mcats');
        $this->tplData['cats_count'] = $this->Mcats->countAll();
        $this->tplData['cats'] = $this->Mcats->fetch();
 $this->_setContent('cats');

Comment: Try print_r($this->tplData);exit(); at the begining of _setContent() : what do you get ?

Comment: Instead of global vars, you should use config as suggested above. Define is for constants.

Comment: @Julien Meilleur is empty! nothing is there

Comment: OK please upload more php content, including the function which setup the tplData variable. Did you try config() solution as seen above ?